# PuppetDB configurtion not working

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to configure puppetDB on the same puppet master server. I followed the puppet documentation, installed the database and configured the puppet to use database.

when I run `puppet agent --test` command its giving below error message.

I didn't see any process running in port 8081, I see puppet java process running on port 8140.

How can I resolve this error?

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Could not retrieve facts for webserver: Failed to find facts from PuppetDB at puppet:8140: Failed to execute '/pdb/query/v4/nodes/webserver/facts' on at least 1 of the following 'server_urls': https://puppetdb:8081
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Warning: Error connecting to puppetdb on 8081 at route /pdb/query/v4/nodes/webserver/facts, error message received was 'Connection refused - connect(2) for "puppetdb" port 8081'. Failing over to the next PuppetDB server_url in the 'server_urls' list
Error: Cached facts for webserver failed: Failed to find facts from PuppetDB at puppet:8140: Failed to execute '/pdb/query/v4/nodes/webserver/facts' on at least 1 of the following 'server_urls': https://puppetdb:8081
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching facts for webserver
Warning: Error connecting to puppetdb on 8081 at route /pdb/cmd/v1?checksum=039e22c7bf98e9cbf2f08169047d288c9b451c73&version=5&certname=webserver&command=replace_facts, error message received was 'Connection refused - connect(2) for "puppetdb" port 8081'. Failing over to the next PuppetDB server_url in the 'server_urls' list
Error: Failed to execute '/pdb/cmd/v1?checksum=039e22c7bf98e9cbf2f08169047d288c9b451c73&version=5&certname=webserver&command=replace_facts' on at least 1 of the following 'server_urls': https://puppetdb:8081
Error: Could not retrieve local facts: Failed to execute '/pdb/cmd/v1?checksum=039e22c7bf98e9cbf2f08169047d288c9b451c73&version=5&certname=webserver&command=replace_facts' on at least 1 of the following 'server_urls': https://puppetdb:8081
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not retrieve local facts: Failed to execute '/pdb/cmd/v1?checksum=039e22c7bf98e9cbf2f08169047d288c9b451c73&version=5&certname=webserver&command=replace_facts' on at least 1 of the following 'server_urls': https://puppetdb:8081
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you checked the SSL certs stored in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl` are matching with the `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/<certnameof your puppetserver.FQDN>` .

This can be verified by

## puppetdb ssl-setup

Sample entry

```
puppetdb ssl-setup

PEM files in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl already exists, checking integrity.
Setting ssl-host in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-port in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-key in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-cert in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
```

Let me know if you have further issues .I have had the same issue and rectified by removing the `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl` directory and rerun the  "`puppetdb ssl-setup`" command.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason puppetdb process went down that's why no process running on port 8081. I have restarted puppetdb process, then `agent -test` command stated connecting to the webserver.

Here is the output of puppetdb service in centos 7.

```
# systemctl status puppetdb
● puppetdb.service - puppetdb Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetdb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-03-28 18:26:58 EDT; 1h 20min ago
 Main PID: 5503 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetdb.service
           └─5503 /usr/bin/java -Xmx192m -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -cp /opt/puppetlabs/...
```